PixiJS - I have to double click to open the Pause screen. Why is that?
In trying to find out why the pause menu opens when the pause button is double clicked instead of being clicked once. It’s a web application which I haven’t made and I’ve never worked with PixiJS.
I’ve tried looking at the browser source files but I couldn’t find the reason.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
